# Second homotopy of $S^1\vee S^2 \vee T^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

How can I prove that the second homotopy group of 
$S^1\vee S^2 \vee T^2$ is infinitely generated?

I know that the second homotopu groups of
$S^2$ and $T^2$ are finitely generated, so is kind of contra-intuitive for me.

Comment: $\pi_2$ is $H_2$ of the universal cover. Try to construct the universal cover explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

if $p:E\to B$ is a covering, then $\pi_2(p):\pi_2(E)\to\pi_2(B)$ is an isomorphism.

consider the following covering with base $S^1\vee S^2\vee T^2$: let the total space be a line $\mathbb R$ with attached copies of $S^2$ and $T^2$ in every integer point; the map $\mathbb R\to S^1, x\mapsto e^{2\pi i x}$ extends on the whole space in the obvious way.

finally, this total space is homotopy equivalent to bouquet of infinite copies of $S^2$ and $T^2$.